# Who defines regular expressions?

Tags: regex, standards

The W3C defines the HTML standard, CSS standard, and some other standards. I know there are other groups who define standards as well. Who defines the syntax of regular expressions?

Comment: Don't know who they are but I'd like whatever they smoke

Comment: If their was a real standard, implementations would not vary as much as they do (e.g. in whether characters have special meanings iff they are escaped or iff they are not escaped).

Comment: "The nice thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from." -- Andrew S. Tanenbaum

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regular expressions are covered by several standard bodies, including IEEE standard 1003.1 (so called Posix): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html

However, there are plenty of other approaches to regular expression syntax, the other popular one being Perl (PCRE). For a nice overview of all major regular expression implementations, including extensions, check out this useful resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html

Answer (score 17):

Regular expressions originated from unix and are a part of the Perl language. If a regular expression language is similar to Perl's regular expressions, it is called Perl Compatible Regular Expressions ([**`PCRE`**](http://pcre.org/))

Comment: Fun fact: PCREs and similar extensions have virtually nothing to do with regular languages - they're much more expressive (which is not always a good thing).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato all regex flavors with backrefs are *not regular*. That's most of them (including those that are much simpler than PCRE and the like).

Comment: @Qtax : I'm aware of that, my intent was to amend this answer, which seemed to suggest that the origin of regular expressions as a concept is strongly tied to Perl.

Answer (score 11):

Here are some organizations who have defined regular expressions:

- [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html)
- [Gnome](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-regex-syntax.html)
- [Oracle (PDF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/application-development/twp-regular-expressions-133133.pdf)
- [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k)
- [ECMA](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10)
- [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-SYNTAX-DETAILS)

And some individuals:

- [Larry Wall: pattern matching](http://www.perl6.org/archive/doc/design/apo/A05.html)
- [Henry Spencer's RegExp Engine Revisited](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4421/Henry-Spencer-s-Regexp-Engine-Revisited)
- [Regex Legends](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-legends/comment-page-1)
- [Ken Thompson](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=363347.363387)

And here is a series on regular expressions:

- [Regular Expression Matching can be Simple and Fast
  (but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)
- [Regular Expression Matching: the Virtual Machine Approach](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html)
- [Regular Expression Matching in the Wild](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html)
- [How Google Code Search Worked](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp4.html)

And here are a few engines:

- [re2: an efficient, principled regular expression library](https://github.com/google/re2)
- [rex_util](http://www.geonius.com/software/libgpl/rex_util.html)

And here is some source code:

- [tclRegexp](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/raw/generic/tclRegexp.c?name=b596b992231532f766c14ac5e4966887ee2f77b5)
- [pcre](http://vcs.pcre.org/viewvc/code/trunk/)
- [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.cc)

Answer (score 7):

There are many implementations, Perl's is the most popular one, used in many tools and libraries. As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) states:

> Perl regular expressions have become *a de facto* standard, having a rich and powerful set of atomic expressions.

Answer (score 6):

There are definitions under the IEEE POSIX standards (as mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) for POSIX compliance, but I guess not everyone follows these.