# How to use sed and/or regex to trim a line in a file using bash?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

This seems like it should be simple, but I've spent far too much time searching. How can I use sed and regex to trim off all words in a line after the fourth word?

For instance from:

```
19900101, This is a title
19091110, This is a really long title
```

I would like to have

```
19900101, This is a
19091110, This is a
```

I've tried answers like this one [Regex to extract first 3 words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345973/regex-to-extract-first-3-words-from-a-string), but I'm using Mac OSX, so I get context address errors.

Comment: The resource you link to uses a regex dialect which isn't supported by *any* `sed` version I am familiar with. You could try Perl, or figure out how to portably express things like `\s` in "traditional" regex. (It's not terribly hard. I'll post an answer to the linked question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done using `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 file

19900101, This is a
19091110, This is a
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '{NF=4} 1' file

19900101, This is a
19091110, This is a
```

Comment: Both of these work perfectly! Would you mind explaining the syntax?

Comment: awk command sets `NF` (# of fields) to 4 thus discarding everything after that. `cut` command cuts fields from position `1-4`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s*\S*//5g' file
```

Remove the fifth or more words from the line.