# Regex fetch text align-left

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to the Regex world and I've browse many site without finding what I'm looking for. 
I have a file where I need to fetch the address. The address is align-left of the paper (there's text in the same line at the right).

```
Some information on multiple line (6)
that I don't need and can't paste because
it contains some personal information. 
So imagine a lot of text here...
So imagine a lot of text here...
So imagine a lot of text here...

Sold To                                              Bill To
Some Cie                                             Some Other Cie
1111 chemin some-road                                2222 chemin some-other-road
City-Here QC J0Q 1W0                                 Other City-Here QC J0Q 1W0 
Canada                                               Canada
```

I need to fetch the text in the 'Sold To' side.
I tried to use the \r but it returns nothing! 
I don't know how to fetch the text from the start of the line until there's a bunch of spaces.
Ex: Some Cie (if more than 1 spaces, go to next line)

then I have: `Sold\sTo(?=\s{2,100})` but it won't work while `(?=\s{2, 100})` returns everything!!!

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346066/11729430): `^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+).*`, which is very close to what I want, but I don't understand the whole thing. I would like to match from 2 to 5 words.

Then I have this: `^([A-Za-z0-9-]*)(?=\s{2,100})` which I thought would match At the beginning of the line until there's more than 2 spaces.
What am I getting wrong?

I need to do this in pure Regex (no flags allowed).

I'm completely lost. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close on your last attempt. Here's what I came up with:

```
^.+?(?=[^\S\n]{2,})
```

Explanation:

- `.+` - One or more characters

  - `?` - Non-greedy, to give the next part priority, i.e. avoid matching a bunch of spaces
- `[^\S\n]` - Any whitespace character except newline (this is like `\s` minus `\n`)

  - `{2,}` - Two or more

Matches from the example:

```
Sold To
Some Cie
1111 chemin some-road
City-Here QC J0Q 1W0
Canada
```

[Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/azMgBQ/1)

Simple example in Python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^.+?(?=[^\S\n]{2,})')

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m:
            print(m.group())
```

Comment: It's working, but only if flag 'Global' and 'multiline' enabled. Is there a way to make it work without specifying those? I'm using a tool that doesn't allow me to specify any flags

Comment: I found out (m?) enabled multiline. Now I'm pretty sure the issue is coming from my tool. Thanks!

Comment: @mrinfo Global is not a real flag in Python. Instead you use a different function, like `re.search` vs `re.findall`. Regex101 just uses it for convenience. As well you don't need multiline if you iterate over the lines. I posted a simple example.

Comment: in fact, it's because I'm using a tool that uses python, I can't write my own python method, only regex in a yml file. To be honest, it's kinda weird... When I use my real file, it's fetching way too much line, I need to add some delimiters in there I think