# Shorthand character class not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

If I pass a word as an argument by:

```
$./file.sh hello
```

it gives Even as output when it should print "Argument should be a number"

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ -z $1 ]]
then
        echo "Argument expected"
else 
        if [[ $1 =~ "\D" ]] #This does not work as expected
        then
                echo "Argument should be a number"
        else
                a=$1%2
                if [[ a -eq 0 ]]
                then
                        echo "Even"
                elif [[ a -eq 1 ]]
                then
                        echo "Odd"
                fi  
        fi  
fi

#End of program
```

When I change "\D" to "[^0-9]" in the if statement, it works as expected and prints "Argument should be a number" to the console.
Don't they both have the same meaning? If not, in what way are the two different from each other?

Comment: BTW, putting quotes on the right-hand side of `=~` tell the shell to treat that as a literal string and not a regex. (However, even if it *were* a regex it wouldn't be parsed as an instruction to match non-digits for the reason given).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash regex simply does not support PCRE regex syntax.

You might want to read up on different regex dialects and their history.

See e.g. [Why are there so many different regular expression dialects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298007/why-are-there-so-many-different-regular-expression-dialects)

Answer (score 4):

Bash uses POSIX Extended Regular Expressions, not PCRE. Instead of escape sequences like `\D`, it uses [Bracket Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). The bracket expression for digits is

```
[:digit:]
```

and to match non-digits, you use this inside a character class with the negation operator:

```
[^[:digit:]]
```

As you can see, this is longer than just writing `[^0-9]`, so it's not really a shorthand. It's useful for portability to other locales, since it will include their digits as well.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX equivalent of `\D` is `[^[:digit:]]`.