# Match tags in Github action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to match tags containing 'alpha' but not 'deploy' when my GHA runs

For example:

```
Match
1.0-alpha.1

No match
1.0-alpha.1-deploy
1.0-deploy
```

GHA

```
name: Not Deploy tag

on: 
  push:
    tags:
      - *alpha*[^-]deploy
```

I am getting the following error message

```
push event contained invalid tags patterns: *alpha*[^-]deploy*
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet? It doesn't suggest that `^` is supported, you likely want a negating pattern starting with `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm the error message you could summon that the tags pattern is invalid.

```
*alpha*[^-]deploy
```

This looks a bit that you would like to introduce a negative character class as in common regular expression dialects. (Cf. *[Why are there so many different regular expression dialects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2298007/367456)*)

However, tag (and branch and file) pattern in Microsoft Github Actions do not have a comparable concept of character class negation in their pattern.

However they do have the concept of a character class:

> `[]` Matches one character listed in the brackets or included in ranges. Ranges can only include `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `0-9`. For example, the range `[0-9a-z]` matches any digit or lowercase letter. For example, `[CB]at` matches Cat or Bat and `[1-2]00` matches `100` and `200`. *(ref: [Filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet))*

Given there must not be a hyphen-minus ("-") in front of *develop*, you could then place there a working representative of what you had in mind with the negated character class.

For example, as the use of any characters other than A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and the hyphen is not recommended anyway to be used in the tag name, this could be all of them minus the hyphen-minus:

```
*alpha*[A-Za-z0-9]deploy     # *alpha*[^-]deploy
```

Another way is to first include every tag including the one not wanted, then excluding the specific tag. This requires multiple patterns, so may add complexity:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'alpha*deploy'
      - '!alpha*-deploy'
```

Even more examples you can find in the product usage manual: *[Example: Including and excluding branches and tags](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-and-excluding-branches-and-tags)* which has the following description and explains how the different workflow document properties work together with negated patterns:

> ##### Example: Including and excluding branches and tags
>
> You can't use `branches` and `branches-ignore` to filter the same event in a single workflow. Similarly, you can't use `tags` and `tags-ignore` to filter the same event in a single workflow. If you want to both include and exclude branch or tag patterns for a single event, use the `branches` or `tags` filter along with the `!` character to indicate which branches or tags should be excluded.
>
> If you define a branch with the `!` character, you must also define at least one branch without the `!` character. If you only want to exclude branches, use `branches-ignore` instead. Similarly, if you define a tag with the `!` character, you must also define at least one tag without the `!` character. If you only want to exclude tags, use `tags-ignore` instead.
>
> The order that you define patterns matters.
>
> - A matching negative pattern (prefixed with `!`) after a positive match will exclude the Git ref.
> - A matching positive pattern after a negative match will include the Git ref again.
>
> The following workflow will run on pushes to `releases/10` or `releases/beta/mona`, but not on `releases/10-alpha` or `releases/beta/3-alpha` because the negative pattern `!releases/**-alpha` follows the positive pattern.
>
> ```yaml
> on:
>   push:
>     branches:
>       - 'releases/**'
>       - '!releases/**-alpha'
> ```
>
> *(ref: multiple authors; CC-BY-4.0, MIT licenses found; [source](https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/data/reusables/actions/workflows/section-run-on-specific-branches-or-tags.md))*